# Include image into email with Python but not show it as attachment in iOs

Tags: python, html, image, email

I would like to send automated emails using Python and these emails should include some PNG files. I have already seen the usual code snippet to include images:

```
email = MIMEMultipart()
image = open(path + '/email/logo.png', 'rb')
logo = MIMEImage(image.read())
logo.add_header('Content-ID', '<logo>')
logo.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename='logo')
email.attach(logo)
image.close()
```

This works good in Outlook but my concern is when I open the email in iOS native mail application, the images are displayed as attached file at the top of the email, in addition to inline in the email. The rendering gets pretty ugly as the user would see all the images first and then scroll down until the body of the email where they are properly placed inline.

Is there a way to embed inline images without having them showing as attachment, for both Outlook and iOs?